# nuxt-mongoose module: Failed to resolve import "#nuxt/mongoose"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mongoose, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to integrate my Nuxt project with the nuxt-mongoose module.
(https://nuxt-mongoose.nuxt.space/getting-started/setup)

But I'm encountering a problem, even if I've followed all the steps.

First of all I installed the package

```
npm install nuxt-mongoose -D
```

Then I set up the .env and nuxt.config.ts

```
// nuxt.config.ts

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },

  css: [
    'vuetify/styles/main.sass'
  ],

  build: {
    transpile: ['vuetify']
  },

  modules: [
    'nuxt-mongoose',
  ],

  nitro: {
  },

  mongoose: {
    uri: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
    options: {},
    modelsDir: 'models'
  }
})
```

So I created a schema, following the wiki one

```
// server/models/user.schema.js

import {defineMongooseModel} from "#nuxt/mongoose"; //Here is where I'm getting the error

export const UserSchema = defineMongooseModel({
    name: 'UserSchema',

    schema: {
        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
        },

        email: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },

        password: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

Even if I followed what's in the wiki, when running `npm run dev`, I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR  Failed to resolve 
import "#nuxt/mongoose" from "server\models\user.schema.js". 
Does the file exist?
```

I've checked and actually the module export exists and so the method used, so I don't know why it isn't working.

I've tried to remove the `import {defineMongooseModel} from "#nuxt/mongoose"` as seen in other internet pages, but then the error says that it doesn't find that method.

I've tryied to remove and install the package `nuxt-mongoose` multiple times, without success.

Comment: Should that not be `@nuxt/mongoose`, importing from a _scoped package_?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Actually no, also in the official wiki I linked it uses `#nuxt/mongoose`, and to other people seems to work, so I think that is not a problem related to the import itself

Comment: What version you are using?

Comment: @ReaganM here's the package.json https://pastebin.com/CK3QbiJj

Comment: I tested the module based on your configuration and it's working on my end

Comment: @ReaganM strange, maybe something wrong in my project or packages?

Comment: Can you share us the repo of your project? If that is okay with you

Comment: @ReaganM I don't have a public repository, but I've uploaded it on google drive, so that you can download or see it https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1U-k1f_Fv5_0cqT-yeLbcTAURd3xL1CG7?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon checking the link you sent, your schema configuration is fine. The problem is, the codes inside the `~/pages/index.vue`. If I am not mistaken, files that are in the server are only accessible inside the server folder except the API routes.

The codes inside the `index.vue` in the pages, and replace it with this.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn @click="saveTestUser()">Prova prova</v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

async function saveTestUser() {
  console.log('clicked')
  $fetch('/api/users/create', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
      name: 'Giggio',
      email: 'youremail@gmail.com',
      password: 'snmpassword'
    }
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('Success')
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
</script>
```

`~/server/api/create.post.js`

```js
export default defineEventHandler( async ( event ) => {
    try {
        const body = await readBody( event )
        await UserSchema.create( body )
        return 200

    } catch ( error ) {
        console.log( error )
        return createError( { statusCode: 500, statusMessage: 'Something went wrong.' } )
    }
} )
```

Tested and it works!

Comment: That way actually the problem, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove configs I added while trying to configure [Zod Mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-zod)

`tsconfig.json`

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "strict": true
}
```

Inside of `nuxt.config.ts`

```
typescript: {
  typeCheck: true,
},
```